# Problems with Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: ubuntu

I have some problem with Ubuntu Software Center. Once I open it, it closes automatically without any permission.

When I run it through the terminal, this is the feedback I get:

```
vangjush@vangjush:~$ software-center
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'**
```

whereas when I try to reinstall software center I get this error that stops the installation:

```
vangjush@vangjush:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
sudo] password for vangjush: 

**SystemError: E:Malformed line 57 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)**
```

This is the 57th line of the source list /etc/apt/sources.list deb
 **http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner**

Comment: Would you mind telling us line 57 (and few lines around) in your /etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: @hvtuananh : you can see the line on my post. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried commenting out line 57 of your sources list and then running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

(To comment-out something, you have to put a "#" at the beginning of the line.")

If that command fails, you probably need to rebuild your sources.list. If it works, post a properly formatted copy of your sources.list here so we can see why that line or the line before or after is "malformed."

(Was going to make this is a comment but I don't have any enough cred to simply comment.)

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5639695/ you can see me source list from this weblink. I couldn't safe the changes at this file because when I try to safe the changes it says **access denied**

Comment: You need to have superuser privileges to edit your source list, i.e. you need to use "sudo" when you open the file using a text editor.

For instance, one of the most universal text editors is nano, so to edit this file and save changes, you'd issue the following command: `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`. Then you would make your changes and type the following commands to save and exit: `CTRL-o` and `CTRL-x`.

Comment: I would comment out all the repos at the bottom after the quantal ones: the "precise" ones and the "natty" ones and run `sudo apt-get update` with just "quantal" repos. You also have "precise" repos in there twice. Those names, by the way, "quantal," "precise," and "natty" refer to different Ubuntu versions. Your version appears to be quantal, so you should be fine with packages from that repo.

Comment: Thnx a lot. Everything works fine. You did help me a lot. Respect Vangjushi